# How to convert DataContext to another type in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

For example I have two classes:

```
class SomeClass {
     public decimal Value1 => ...;
     public decimal Value2 => ...;
}

class SomeClassWrapper {
     private readonly SomeClass someClass;
     public decimal Value1 => someClass.Value1;
     public decimal Value2 => someClass.Value2;
     public decimal Delta => someClass.Value2 - someClass.Value1;
     public SomeClassWrapper(SomeClass someClass) {...}
}
```

`SomeClass` is passed to my `DataTemplate` by third party code. But I need to use `SomeClassWrapper`.

So, how can I convert `SomeClass` to `SomeClassWrapper` in xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use `IValueConverter`.

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( SomeClass ), typeof( SomeClassWrapper ) )]
public class SomeClassWrapperConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( value ) );
        if (value is SomeClass == false) throw new ArgumentException( $"Value ({value?.GetType().Name}) is invalid" );
        if (targetType != typeof( object )) throw new ArgumentException( $"Target type ({targetType.Name}) is invalid" );

        return new SomeClassWrapper ( (SomeClass) value );
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


<SomeClassWrapperConverter x:Key="SomeClassWrapperConverter" />

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SomeClassWrapperConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `ObjectDataProvider` with `ObjectType="{x:Type local:SomeClassWrapper}`. And then set this `ObjectDataProvider` as `DataContext`.

Unfortunately there is no simple way to pass DataContext into this `ObjectDataProvider`. There is a hack described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/382c6941-02d3-4c5c-8685-6d15bf996524/is-it-possible-to-pass-current-datacontext-as-contructorparameter-of-objectdataprovider?forum=wpf).

You can't pass `DataContext` to `ObjectDataProvider` but you can do it via special Proxy class.

```
public class Proxy : Freezable {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "Data", typeof( object ), typeof( Proxy ), new UIPropertyMetadata() );

    public object Data {
        get { return GetValue( DataProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( DataProperty, value ); }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() {
        return new Proxy();
    }

}

public class ProxyStaticResource : StaticResourceExtension {

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        var proxy = (Proxy) base.ProvideValue( serviceProvider );
        return proxy.Data;
    }

}


<local:Proxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" Data="{Binding}" />

<Grid.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="TooltipInfo" ObjectType="{x:Type local:TooltipInfo}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <local:ProxyStaticResource ResourceKey="DataContextProxy" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Grid.Resources>

<Grid.DataContext>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="TooltipInfo" />
</Grid.DataContext>
```

Maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

More convenient way is to use `MarkupExtension`.

```
public class DataContextConverter : MarkupExtension {

    public Type TargetType { get; set; }


    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        if (TargetType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( TargetType ) );
        if (serviceProvider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( serviceProvider ) );

        var targetProvider = (IProvideValueTarget) serviceProvider.GetService( typeof( IProvideValueTarget ) );
        if (targetProvider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( targetProvider ) );


        if (targetProvider.TargetObject is DependencyObject == false) return this; // deferral mechanism


        var @object = (FrameworkElement) targetProvider.TargetObject;
        return Activator.CreateInstance( TargetType, @object.DataContext );
    }


}


<Grid DataContext="{local:DataContextConverter TargetType='local:SomeClassWrapper'}" />
```